# How to stop double-bounce FROM sender in postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, spam

I am getting huge amount of these in my mail log, and unable to find its originator. What could be the reason? Here is log entry:

```
postfix/cleanup[9626]: 4413082E40: message-id=<20140220102521.4413082E40@mail.mmnc.co.uk>
postfix/qmgr[9367]: 4413082E40: from=<double-bounce@mail.mmnc.co.uk>, size=255, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Comment: Have you added or changed anything recently? If things like content_filters, or milters are not functioning correctly, you can see errors similar to this.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Can you grep out all examples of that message-id ?

Comment: @Farhan : Mmmh... looks like two different process with different purposes log the message they handle one time each. Splitting the log of "*cleanup*" and "*qmgr*" can be temporary workaround.

Answer (score 7):

The double-bounce messages are used by postfix for address verification.

You may find more detail here...

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.